# Problems removing Devise from an application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I was initially using Devise to handle authentication on my application but as I'm switching to a password-less, completely OpenID/OAuth authentication system, I decided to remove Devise.

I started by "destroy"ing the models,views, removed the gem from the Gemfile, removed the initializer file (config/initializers/devise.rb) and a locale file I found (config/locales/devise.en.yml)

I've look through the stack and the source code (GREP'ed it all) and couldn't find any reference to devise.

The problem is that now my application keeps returning me this error:

```
No such file or directory - /home/develop/0523a/fivetalk/config/locales/devise.en.yml
```

Does anyone have an idea of where the problem is?

Here's the stack

```
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:25:in `stat'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:25:in `updated_at'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:25:in `map'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:25:in `updated_at'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:29:in `execute_if_updated'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:23:in `_callback_before_5'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:45:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:46:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/server.rb:213:in `start'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:30
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:27
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

Comment: You re-ran bundle install after removing the gem from the Gemfile?

Comment: worse than that. I didn't restart the server :/ Thanks for the tip anyways!

Comment: Yeah, any time you change anything outside of `app/` and `config/routes.rb` you'll have to restart your server.

Comment: @tadman: yeah, I just learned that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(super delayed)

I had to follow the steps described in the question, and after that I needed to restart the server, which I hand't done. This was the solution for the problem. Just in case other people see this and don't read the comments.